# How to close evince after PDF presentation?

Tags: pdf, window-manager, evince

In automating a tutorial process, `evince` is to show a PDF file in presentation mode, and automatically close the window after that. Option `-s` starts the presentation mode, but after the last page, it shows the file embedded in the GUI. Is there any way to **automatically** close after the presentation ends? Be it a way to parametrize `evince` or external commands that kill the process, launched (say) in a basch file, and controlled by a window manager (say `wmctrl`). (Any other core command, alternative to `evince` would work.)

Comment: Alt-F4 works in Gnome.

Comment: @Nick OK, "automatically" added in bold in the question, I assumed it was clear.